# How to echo user input within mail body

Tags: php, email, phpmailer

I'm working on php mailer and I've tried all possible means to echo out the user input within the mail body, but i keep getting an error. below is my code

```
$mail->isHTML(true);


$body="<p><center><img src='https://example.com/images/mail-icon.png'><br>Example</center></p>


<center><h3>You are welcome</h3></center><br>
<p>

$mail->='$_POST['fname']'
```

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: Your `$body="...` did not close with double quotes. The code `$mail->='...'` is not valid syntax.

Answer (score 0):

Answer for your question is very simple. So, I dont know how your form looks, but all you need to do is:

```
$body=$fname;
```

Perhaps, inside $body you can write also html message, as `$body="<p>Dear,<br> You just received a message from:". $fname ."</p>";`